# How to convert query string in hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have a query string like this:

```
id=60087888;jid=16471827;from=advance;action=apply
```

or it can be like this :

```
id=60087888&jid=16471827&from=advance&action=apply
```

Now from this i want to create a hash that will have key as id and its value

I have done this

```
my %in;
      $buffer = 'resid=60087888;jobid=16471827;from=advance;action=apply';
      @pairs = split(/=/, $buffer);
      foreach $pair (@pairs){
           ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
           $in{$name} = $value; 
      }

print %in;
```

But the issue is in the query string it can be semin colon or & so how can we do this please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer:

```
my %in;
      $buffer = 'resid=60087888;jobid=16471827;from=advance;action=apply';
      @pairs = split(/[&,;]/, $buffer);
      foreach $pair (@pairs){
           ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
           $in{$name} = $value; 
      }
delete $in{resid};
print keys %in;
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to solve it with new code; this is what CPAN modules are for. Specifically in this case, [`URI::Query`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Query)

```
use URI::Query;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = URI::Query->new( "resid=60087888;jobid=16471827;from=advance;action=apply" );
my %hash = $q->hash;

print Dumper( \%hash );
```

Gives

```
{ action => 'apply',
  from   => 'advance',
  jobid  => '16471827',
  resid  => '60087888' }
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already an answer that works - but personally I might tackle it like this:

```
my %in = $buffer =~ m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
```

What this does is use regular expressions to pattern match either side of the equals sign.

It does so in pairs - effectively - and as a result is treated by a sequence of key-values in the hash assignment.

Note - it does assume you've not got special characters in your keys/values, and that you have no null values. (Or if you do, they'll be ignored - you can use `(\w*)` instead if that's the case).

But you get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'from' => 'advance',
          'jid' => '16471827',
          'action' => 'apply',
          'id' => '60087888'
        };
```

Alternatively:

```
my %in = map { split /=/ } split ( /[^=\w]/, $buffer );
```

We split using 'anything that isn't word or equals' to get a sequence, and then split on equals to make the same key-value pairs. Again - certain assumptions are made about valid delimiter/non-delimiter characters.

Comment: This doesn't allow for "empty" values in the string.

`'id=60087888&jid=16471827&from=advance&action=apply&blank=&not_blank=1';`

Gives unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game, but....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $query = 'id=60087888&jid=16471827&from=advance&action=apply&blank=&not_blank=1';

my $cgi = CGI->new($query);

my %hash = $cgi->Vars();

print Dumper \%hash;
```

will produce:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'not_blank' => '1',
          'jid' => '16471827',
          'from' => 'advance',
          'blank' => '',
          'action' => 'apply',
          'id' => '60087888'
        };
```

Which has the added benefit of dealing with keys that might not have values in the source string.

Some of the other examples will produce:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'id' => '60087888',
          '1' => undef,
          'jid' => '16471827',
          'from' => 'advance',
          'blank' => 'not_blank',
          'action' => 'apply'
        };
```

which may not be desirable.

I would have used `URI::Query` @LeoNerd 's answer, but I didn't have the ability to install a module in my case and CGI.pm was handy.

Answer (score 0):

also, you could

```
my $buffer = 'id=60087888&jid=16471827&from=advance&action=apply'; 
my %hash = split(/&|=/, $buffer);
```

which gives:

```
$hash = {
          'jid' => '16471827',
          'from' => 'advance',
          'action' => 'apply',
          'id' => '60087888'
};
```

This is **VERY** fragile, so I wouldn't advocate using it.

Comment: This takes advantage of the fact that, in Perl, hashes are arrays with an even number of elements.